# Paradox from enchanted objects

Tags: world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension

I was wondering the way paradox should be handled with enchanted objects (like wonders or, prime enchanted objects or beings). Should the object generate paradox to the crafter at the moment of its creation or, to the user each time it is .... used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Paradox will come when the object is used (assuming you've created a vulgar effect).  Reality doesn't care if you say some magic words at the rock and then claim it's enchanted.  It reacts if that rock starts randomly teleporting itself ten feet to the left.

This is what makes some Technocracy toys so useful. They don't shoot fireballs out of magic wands. They shoot lasers out of laser guns. Sure, that's clearly "an advanced prototype" or something, but it comes close enough to avoid the worst backlash.

Being clever about what you enchant and how use it afterwards is worth it.

Comment: Is this Rules as Written? I remember reading old books of Mage stating that Paradox accumulates in the object and when it cannot contain more it kind of unleashes everything it was onto the poor user (in Factor Chaos, Samuel High dies like that, right?)